# Improve efficiency of python for loop counting items against IDs in nested list

Tags: python, list, for-loop, list-comprehension

I'm trying to improve the efficiency of a script that takes a nested list representing a data table, with a column of IDs (each of which might have many entries). The script counts the number of IDs that have more than 100 entries, and more than 200 entries.

Is there a way I can not have to cycle through the list each time with the list comprehension maybe?

```
list_of_IDs = [row[4] for row in massive_nested_list] ### get list of ID numbers
list_of_IDs = set(list_of_IDs) ### remove duplicates
list_of_IDs = list(list_of_IDs)
counter200 = 0
counter100 = 0
for my_ID in list_of_IDs:
    temp = [row for row in massive_nested_list if row[4] == my_ID]
    if len(temp) > 200:
        counter200 += 1
    if len(temp) > 100:
        counter100 += 1
```

Comment: use a Counter dict also if len > 200 then it is obviously also > 100

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a [`collections.Counter()` instance](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to count your ids. There is no need to collect all possible ids first. You can then collate counts from there:

```
from collections import Counter

counts = Counter(row[4] for row in massive_nested_list)
counter100 = counter200 = 0
for id, count in counts.most_common():
    if count >= 200:
        counter200 += 1
    elif count >= 100:
        counter100 += 1
    else:
        break
```

Given K unique IDs in N nested lists, your code would take O(KN) loops to count everything; worst case (K == N) that means your solution takes quadratic time (for every additional row you need to do N times more work). The above code reduces this no *one* loop over N items, then another loop over K items, making it a O(N) (linear) algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest method would be to go:

```
temp100 = [row for row in massive_nested_list if row[4] == my_ID and row >= 100 and row < 200]
temp200 = [row for row in massive_nested_list if row[4] == my_ID and row >= 200]
```

then you could go:

```
len(temp200)
```

OR

```
counter200 = len(temp200)
```